# Trying to stop ArrayList from doubling up on method calls

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a lineGraph which is populated by an ArrayList. I am displaying 6 charts on one screen, each one is triggered by a method call / switch statement. The problem is when the next chart is called it still has the information from the previous chart so it "doubles up" and keeps doing this until the program crashes. I'm realatively inexperienced at coding, I was hoping someone could take a look at my code and pinpoint my logical error.

Please see my code snippets below.

```
 private ArrayList<Entry> yVals;

@Override
    public void onClick (View view){

        switch (view.getId()) {

             case R.id.moodLogQuarterly:
                retroFitQuarterly();
                break;

            case R.id.moodLogYearly:
                retroFitYearly();
                break;



 public void retroFitYearly() {

    // Retrofit call to the MYSQL server.
    Call<List<MoodLogLineGraph>> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi().moodLogLineGraphYearly(userId);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<MoodLogLineGraph>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<MoodLogLineGraph>> call, Response<List<MoodLogLineGraph>> response) {

            getLineGraphWithResponse(response);
 }


public void retroFitQuarterly() {

    // Retrofit call to the MYSQL server.
    Call<List<MoodLogLineGraph>> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi().moodLogLineGraphQuarterly(userId);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<MoodLogLineGraph>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<MoodLogLineGraph>> call, Response<List<MoodLogLineGraph>> response) {

            getLineGraphWithResponse(response);
        }


 private void getLineGraphWithResponse(Response<List<MoodLogLineGraph>> response) {

    // All JSON entries form the MYSQL server are parsed into an ArrayList.
       yVals = new ArrayList<>();

    // For loop which dynamically adds all entries to the ArrayList
    // response.body() contains the JSON parsed from the database. The JSON
    // contains all the information requested from the database such as moodId,
    // moodName, posted(date) etc.
    // Getters are used to select specific pieces of information form the JSON array.
    for (MoodLogLineGraph moodLogList : response.body()) {

        // The getter .getMoodBefore contains an int between 1-11. These ints represent
        // the mood the user has inputted to the database i.e 1=happy, 11= Depressed etc.
        // The float val is used to store the integer so it can used in a LineGraph.
        val = (float) moodLogList.getMoodBefore();

        }

        // Obtains the date the mood was recorded from the MYSQL database.
        date = (float) moodLogList.getDay();

        // Adds the values and dates to the LineGraph ArrayList.
        yVals.add(new Entry(date, val));

        // Works out the percentage of positive moods
        percentage = total / response.body().size();
        moodLogPercentage.setText(Math.round(percentage * 100) + "%" + " of your moods are positive");


        //Initialising the LineChart variables which control the presentation.
        LineDataSet set1 = new LineDataSet(yVals, "Data set1");
        set1.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        set1.setLineWidth(2f);
        set1.setDrawValues(false);
        set1.setDrawCircles(false);
        set1.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);
        set1.setCubicIntensity(0.1f);

        ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSet = new ArrayList<>();
        dataSet.add(set1);
        LineData data = new LineData(dataSet);
```

***The rest of the code is just variables which style the line graph.

Comment: You want to clear old data from ArrayList before populating it with new data. Did I get the intentions right?

Comment: I am guessing that you showed us much code we don’t need and not enough of the code we do need. One possible cause may be that whatever class this code came from is used to instantiate a single object shared across your charts, thus only one instance of your member variable `yVals`.